# JObject.SelectToken as JObject Newtonsoft.JSON C#

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I want to query `JObject` and again with result again query in recursive way.

So `JObject.SelectToken` is results the Property. so again Querying the Property is not getting value as it's not a `JObject`.

So please anyone suggest me a way to acheive this.

Sample Code:

```
JObject Jobj = JObject.parse(@"{
  ""patient_demog_information"": {
    ""patient_id"": ""2558765"",
    ""patient_name"": {
      ""given_name"": ""29 th june 2018"",
      ""family_name"": ""0016"",
      ""middle_name"": """",
      ""suffix_name"": """",
      ""prefix_name"": """",
      ""degree_name"": """"
    }
  }
}");
```

So, not directly in step wise i've get middle_name value in patient_name

```
JToken pat_demog = Jobj.SelectToken("$.patient_demog_information");

JToken pat_name = pat_demog.SelectToken("$.patient_name");
```

So here I'm getting `pat_demog`, and by querying it not getting the `pat_name`
because it's a Property not `JObject`.

Comment: What is the output that you are expecting?

Comment: @KevinSmith i want to get "patient_name" property value and again from that result i want to filter "middle_name". so, in this way i want filter out value depend on path "$.patient_demog_information.patient_name.middle_name" in step by step.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure fully what you mean but you can keep using `SelectToken` to keep drilling futher down the tree, for example:

```
JObject Jobj = JObject.Parse(@"{
  ""patient_demog_information"": {
    ""patient_id"": ""2558765"",
    ""patient_name"": {
      ""given_name"": ""29 th june 2018"",
      ""family_name"": ""0016"",
      ""middle_name"": """",
      ""suffix_name"": """",
      ""prefix_name"": """",
      ""degree_name"": """"
    }
  }
}");

JToken pat_demog = Jobj.SelectToken("$.patient_demog_information");

JToken pat_name = pat_demog.SelectToken("$.patient_name");

JValue family_name = (JValue)pat_name.SelectToken("$.family_name");

Console.WriteLine(family_name.Value);
```

The above casts to a `JValue` however we could just cast directly to a string

```
string value = (string)pat_name.SelectToken("$.family_name");

Console.WriteLine(value);
```

Comment: SelectToken returning the Token Value, not the Token itself so by further filtering is not working!

Comment: Ah right just cast it to a `JValue` or the value that the field is... eg `string`

Comment: `JToken pat_demog = Jobj.SelectToken("$.patient_demog_information");`     
pat_demog contains value like this 
`""patient_id"": ""2558765"",
    ""patient_name"": {
      ""given_name"": ""29 th june 2018"",
      ""family_name"": ""0016"",
      ""middle_name"": """",
      ""suffix_name"": """",
      ""prefix_name"": """",
      ""degree_name"": """"
    }`    
so here the problem is filtering this JValue! Because it is not object, by filtering it with `patient_name` value returns null!

Comment: @AbdulRahman This works perfectly fine, checkout the dotnetfiddle - https://dotnetfiddle.net/rcRgLo